# [SailsJS / sails-mongo]SNI name

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

I'm trying to configure a MongoDB connection in SailsJS through sails-mongo, but no matter how I configure it, I'm getting this error.

```
MongoError: no SNI name sent, make sure using a MongoDB 3.4+ driver/shell.
```

Could you assist me please?

Comment: Please add your connection configuration esp `host` field.

Comment: devMongodbMLAB: {
    adapter: 'sails-mongo',
    host: 'ds111940.mlab.com',
    port: 11940,
    user: '****',
    password: '****',
    database: 'texleech'
  },

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the error message.  You are using a pre 3.4 driver.  A v3.2 or v3.3 will not send the proper information to a v3.4 server instance.